# SassError: media query expression must begin with '('

Tags: css, reactjs, vue.js, svelte, sass-loader

I had this problem even I didn't manage to sleep, guys

my codes are  like these

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import '~/assets/scss/main.scss'
    .home_nav{
        nav {

        }
    }
</style>
```

the error is

[image]

please, someone, to help me

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## It's a missing semicolon(;)

i found the problem was typo error i was missing `;` on     `@import '~/assets/scss/main.scss'`

> **Note:** even if this error occurred in `vue.js` the solution does not apply only in `Vue` but anywhere you use `node-sass` and
> `sass-loader`  ( now called `sass`)

then it had to be like this

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import '~/assets/scss/main.scss';
    .home_nav{
        nav {

        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Same problem, thanks! The node-sass parser and the error message could be better... :-D

Comment: Damn, you saved my time :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. You are missing semicolon **;** in the end of your import.

```
**@import "./common/colors.scss";**

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```